# Make static hostname visible via DNS (and dynamic IP)

Tags: linux, dhcp, internal-dns

In my local network I manage a csv file which maps MAC addresses to hostnames. This file is used to set the hostname of a client machine when it gets installed, so dynamic hostname assignment is not neccessary. The client receives a dynamic IP address via DHCP though.

Now I want to access the machine on my local network via ssh (ssh user@some_host.local). Since the IP is dynamic, I have to use the hostname.

All machines run on Linux. The DHCP server is isc-dhcp-server. I know I will have to set up DNS and plan to use bind9.

But I am still unsure about how to configure the network. How would I have to configure the DHCP and DNS servers in a way that the setup so far remains "unchanged"?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your network is configured and what is supported.

- You either do what is typical for the Windows workstation hosts, make the hostname a static property of the workstation, assign a dynamic IP-address with DHCP and then have workstation register its current IP-address in your internal DNS for host name based resolving:

  Sometimes simply configuring the DHCP client to submit the hostname / FQDN it wants can be enough. See for example: https://askubuntu.com/q/990537

  Other solutions may require that your Linux system is actually a member of a Windows AD domain.
- The opposite is more a traditional Linux solution and fits in with the administration that you're already maintaining. That is more akin to the network forcing a specific hostname unto a system:

  You configure the DHCP server to use the systems MAC address information to always hand out the same IP-address to the same host. Then you can have static mappings of hostname ==> IP-address and the reverse in your DNS.

Comment: I don't have any Windows clients or servers in my network. Preferrably I do not have to add dozens of mappings to both the DHCP and DNS configs and can keep a single file in a trivial format at a central location. The link looks rather promising.